# What is the difference between running ./file.py and python file.py?

Tags: python, shell, command-line

When I run Python script from the command line

```
./file.py
```

it is interpreted differently(fails with a bunch of errors) from when I run it using:

```
python file.py
```

Why are they executed differently?

Comment: What is the first line of file.py?

Comment: and what exactly do you mean by *"interpreted differently"*? What happens when each way is tried? What platform are you on?

Comment: It's just a start of the program, i.e. import socket.

Comment: So at what point when you run `./file.py` do you expect the operating system to figure out that you actually wanted to execute `python`?

Comment: @ChrisMartin: That's not a completely ignorant thing to expect. After all, Windows will figure it out from the fact that the extension is `.py`, and Windows is almost an operating system. :) And even on many *nix systems, double-clicking the file in Finder/Nautilus/whatever will look at the extension.

Comment: @abarnert I can understand Windows Explorer doing that, but does it also happen at a lower level?

Comment: @ChrisMartin: Yes, `cmd.exe` goes by extension, not by shebangs. (However, to confuse things a bit more, the Python launcher that may be registered to handle `.py` files _does_ look at shebangs…)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Unix-like systems:

- `./file.py` requires `file.py` to be executable (e.g., `chmod a+x file.py`).
- `./file.py` runs the script with whichever interpreter is specified in its shebang line; `python file.py` runs it with whichever interpreter named `python` is highest on your `$PATH`. If you have multiple versions of Python, this can make a big difference.

If you don't know which `python` is highest on your `$PATH`, type `which python` and it will tell you.

If you want the shebang line to run the `python` that's highest on your `$PATH`, write it as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

---

On Windows:

- `./file.py` runs the script with whatever application is registered to handle `*.py` files, whereas `python file.py` runs it with whichever interpreter named `python.exe` is highest on your `%PATH%`. Again, if you have multiple versions of Python, this can make a big difference.

Note that Windows `cmd.exe`, unlike Unix shells, doesn't care about shebangs, only extensions. However, if you've installed a new enough version of Python, the application registered to handle `*.py` files will be the [PEP 397](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) Python launcher, which *does* look at shebangs. (You can also get the launcher [separately](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher) for older versions of Python.)

---

From your comments, the first line is:

> just a start of the program, i.e. import socket

It sounds like you don't have a shebang line at all. That means that, if you're on a Unix-like system, `./file.py` will run it with the default interpreter—which is `/bin/sh` on Unix and most Unix-likes, which isn't a Python interpreter at all. So you will probably get a bunch of confusing errors, probably starting with something like `import: command not found`.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out to folks who are troubled by this the utility of the `which` command to determine which `python` installation is the one that is highest on your `$PATH`.  As you've stated in the answer already -- this is critical.

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem was absence of a shebang line. I was expecting that extension would somehow imply an interpreter ;)

Comment: @GaryWalker: I just realized that the word wrap makes it maybe a little too easy to misread. Let me try to edit it to avoid that.

Comment: Historically, `python file.py` was mandatory (except Python didn't exist then), and it felt like nothing less than a revolution when Unix allowed you to write new commands as scripts.

Comment: @tripleee: Always nice to find someone older than me here. :) The first Unix I ever got to touch was SysV; I can't remember for sure, but probably SVR3; it had nearly-modern `sh` (with functions and all), `curses` and termcaps, `compress` instead of `pack`, …